# websocket сервер на php

Tags: php, websocket, ssl, https

Всем привет.

Есть самописный сервер webscoket на  php, в связке http ws работает все отлично.

Но через само подписанный сертификат ошибка
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Функция stream_socket_accept($socket) возвращает false.
**Код server.php**

```
    $context = stream_context_create();

    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/etc/ssl/private/server.key');

stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/etc/ssl/certs/server.pem');

   stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase','');

    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signe', true);
    $socket =  stream_socket_server("ssl://192.168.43.168:8078",$errno,$errstr,STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context);




    if (!$socket) {
        die("$errstr ($errno)\n");
    }

    $read[] = $socket;

    $db = new dbquery();

    global $jsdata; 
    $authClient = array();
    $write = $except = null;


    while(true)
    {
        $read[] = $socket;

        stream_select($read, $write, $except,1, 0);

        if (in_array($socket, $read))
        {

            try {
                $newSocket = stream_socket_accept($socket);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
            }
```

**client.js**

```
var uri ="wss://192.168.43.168:8078?id="+$('#iduser').val();
var socket = new WebSocket(uri);
```

Comment: А браузер-то этому сертификату доверяет?

Comment: Нет не доверяет, Certificate Error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Comment: Ну так потому и false возвращает, что соединение было сброшено в процессе установки.

Comment: failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH   Что это за ошибка что нибудь в курсе?

Comment: @PavelMayorov я не спец по нетворкингу, но, насколько понимаю, connection reset означает провал еще на уровне tcp-подключения

Comment: @user3035145 сам текст ошибки прямо говорит, что не удалось договориться о шифре для шифрования подключения. Здесь моих знаний совсем не хватает, но, насколько могу предположить, вам нужно заставить сервер работать с теми шифрами, которые доступны клиенту или вообще переключить версию SSL (скорее всего, это задается простыми настройками)

Answer (score 1):

У вас опечатка в опции allow_self_signed:

```
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signe', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Подключил сертификат подписанный центром сертификации.
Все заработало. 
Нужно только создать pem ключ  сервера

```
cat server.crt server.key > server.pem
```

Ну и не забывать везде указывать доменное имя

```
wss:\\domain-name:8078
```